# Creating multiple instances of the same file dynamically in JS (workers)

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, html5-filesystem

So I'm basically doing this (simplified) ...

```
var script = '...some JS code...',
    blob = blob = new Blob([script]),
    worker = [];

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    worker[i] = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}
```

... to dynamically create 10 instances of the same JS file and pass it on to 10 web workers (then a controller/delegator divides a specific task between the 10 for further processing - but this is not important for this question at the moment).

This all works fine, but after examining the code in Chrome developer tools (network) I see that Chrome really creates 10 separate versions of the same file (costing additional milliseconds of initialization - can see the waterfall for every additional file created), even though its the same file.

If I take `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` outside of the loop and into a separate variable and then just pass that variable to the workers in the loop - it doesn't work properly any more - it seems that all workers then share the EXACT same JS file (even though I'd expect that each worker would launch its own separate process).

Any ideas? Could I somehow create `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` just once and then somehow duplicate/clone it? Not sure if that would help or make things different?